# How to create label textarea like blogger in php

Tags: php

Help for creating label text-area like blogger in php.
which separate by coma(,) and also search separate label after coma.
Please help me.

[image]

Comment: http://codevisually.com/jquery-textcomplete-autocomplete-for-textarea/

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843854/comma-separated-multiple-autocomplete-in-one-field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At Last I found what i want. Here what i want.

```
<div class="LabelBox">
  <label>Label</label>
  <textarea id="search_Labels"></textarea>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    function split(val) {
        return val.split(/,\s*/);
    }

    function extractLast(term) {
        return split(term).pop();
    }
    $("#search_Labels").autocomplete({
        minLength: 1,
        source: "search_label.php",
        focus: function() {
            // prevent value inserted on focus
            return false;
        },
        open: function (event, ui) {
        var acData = $(this).data('ui-autocomplete');
        acData
            .menu
            .element
            .find('a')
            .each(function () {
                var me = $(this);
                var keywords = acData.term.split(' ').join('|');
                me.html(me.text().replace(new RegExp("(" + keywords + ")", "i"), '<b>$1</b>'));
            });
    },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            var term = split(this.value);
            // remove the current input
            term.pop();
            // add the selected item
            term.push(ui.item.value);
            // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
            term.push("");
            this.value = term.join(", ");
            return false;
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

Now **search_label.php** Code

```
<?php

    //connect to database

    $s = $_GET['term']; // Get term for search
    // use-full to split label from second label search
    $sa = split( ', ', ( trim( mb_substr( $s, 0, ( strrpos( $s, ',' ) ) ) ) ) );
    $i = ( substr_count( $s, ',' ) > 0 ) ? 1 : 0;
    $s = ltrim( mb_substr( $s, ( strrpos( $s, ',' ) + $i ) ) );
    $ar = '';
    $i = 0;
    if ( $s != '' ) {
        $q = "SELECT `label` FROM `table_name` WHERE `label` LIKE '{$s}%' ORDER BY `label`";
        $q = mysql_query( $q );
        while ( $r = mysql_fetch_array( $q ) ) {
            if ( !in_array( $r['label'], $sa ) ) {
                $ar[$i] = array( "value" => "{$r['label']}" );
                $i++;
            }
        }
        echo json_encode( $ar );
    }

?>
```

Sample output image

[image: Output of inserting multiple label using textarea]